# Using Call Hierarchy

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Java/Eclipse in automated testing (Selenium RC and testNG) for a web app.

Call Hierarchy has been useful for me in certain regards but I haven't been able to figure out how to give me all test methods which use a specific non-test method; the default is to give me all methods which use the method of interest. I just want all the test methods and not the intermediary methods.

So for method 1 - invoked indirectly by Test A - I want to see "method 1/Test A" and not "method 1/intermediary method which invokes method1/Test A." Similarly, if Test B invokes method 1 indirectly then I want to see "method 1/Test A/Test B.

Is there a way to make Call Hierarchy do this? Is there a third-party tool which would do this?

This would really help me in making sure that changes I make to a particular test which uses the method doesn't have unintended runtime consequences on another test.

Thank you.